# How do I create / name dataframes in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

So I'm currently trying to scrape precinct results by county from JSON files on Virginia's Secretary of State. I got code working that gets the data from a URL and creates a dataframe named after the county. To speed up the process, I tried to put the code inside a for loop that iterates through Virginia's counties (which I'm sourcing from a 2020 election by county CSV already on my computer that I constructed from this: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/VOQCHQ), constructs the URL for the county JSON file (since the format's consistent), and saves it to a dataframe. My current code doesn't save the dataframes though, so only the last county remains.

This is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

va <- filter(biden_margin, biden_margin$state_po == "VA")
#i put this line here because the spreadsheet uses spaces to separate "X" and "city" but the URL uses an underline 
va$county_name <- gsub(" ", "_", va$county_name)
#i put this line here because the URLs have "county" in the name, but the spreadsheet doesn't; however the spreadsheet does have "city" for the independent cities, like the URLs (and the independent cities are the observations with FIPS above 51199)
va$county_name <- if_else(va$county_fips > 51199, va$county_name, paste0(va$county_name, "_COUNTY"))
#i did this as a list but i realize this might be a bad idea
governor_data <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(va))

for (i in nrow(va)) {
  precincts <- paste0("https://results.elections.virginia.gov/vaelections/2021%20November%20General/Json/Locality/", va$county_name[i], "/Governor.json")
  name <- paste0(va$county_name[i], "_governor_2021")
  java_source <- stream_in(file(precincts))
  df <- as.data.frame(java_source$Precincts)
  df$county <- java_source$Locality$LocalityName
  df <- unnest(df, cols = c(Candidates))
  df <- subset(df, select = -c(PoliticalParty, BallotOrder))
  df <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = BallotName, values_from = c(Votes, Percentage))
  #tried append before this, got the same result
  governor_data[i] <- assign(name, df)
  
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Consider using a list of data.frames instead of somehow creating names of data.frames in a loop.

Comment: Why not initialize an empty list (before the for-loop) and then make assignments of the dataframes into indexed elements within it. Then you could name them by extracting names using the same indices from the `va` object.